# I can't get the footer to extend to bottom of browser window

Tags: css

So I can't get the footer on this page: http://hiddenhillsweddings.com/ to extend to the bottom of the browser window. I've tried all of the different positional attributes (absolute, relative, etc..) and I've tried all kinds of different combinations with minimum and maximum height at 100% and other values. I have read many threads on this forum about this topic but haven't found a solution. I'm pretty sure what I need is a position: absolute; and a height of 100% but for some reason when I do this the footer extends way past the bottom of the browser and I can't hide the overflow to get rid of the scroll bar. Someone please help me.

Comment: This is good http://ryanfait.com/sticky-footer/

Answer (score 2):

You have just found one of web developers' most usual problems... There are many solutions to this, some pure CSS, other with JavaScript. There are some good tutorials on this subject already written:

- http://matthewjamestaylor.com/blog/keeping-footers-at-the-bottom-of-the-page
- http://fortysevenmedia.com/blog/archives/making_your_footer_stay_put_with_css/

I personally do it via jQuery, I find it to be more reliable. I place the footer below everything, with display:block and normal position. Then I check if the content is smaller than the page, in which case I change the position to absolute and bottom:0;

Once that is done, I check on window resize in case the scenario changes. It's probably not optimal, but it works great:

```
function footer(){
    var offset = $('#footer').offset();
    var footerHeight = $('#footer').height();
    var height = window.innerHeight;
    if(height-offset.top-footerHeight>0)
        $('#footer').css({'position':'absolute', 'bottom':0, 'width':'100%'});
    else
        $('#footer').css({'position':'static'});
}
```

Just make sure you change `#footer` for the ID of your footer element.

Comment: the position absolute and bottom:0 work but I'd really rather keep the spacing between the footer and the content and just have it expand the dark grey color all the way to the bottom of the browser if the content is too short. Will I be able to do this with jQery? Also I have the site built on a wordpress platform and I'm using a custom template so it would be preferable if the footer could be the same code and css across all pages regardless of the content height.

Comment: If you want the footer to *expand* to the bottom of the window, I think you'll have to do it using jQuery. I've tried to do this with css, but haven't had any success. a jQuery solution is trivial.

Comment: The tricky part of a jQuery solution is that it needs to be updated on various events, not only window resize. If you do AJAX calls and modify the DOM, this will not trigger the resize event. I have my own function for this which I'll post in my answer now

Comment: +1 (upvoted)to your answer Chevi. Very helpful. Is there a chance u can add the code for how to check this again on the window resize event.